# How does Moq mock a data for pattern matching?

Tags: c#, moq

The background

```
public interface IEvent {}

public class Event1 : IEvent {}

public class Event2 : IEvent {}
```

Now I have a business logic does this:

```
switch (evt) {
    case Event1 e1: {
        // do something so I can use e1 directly 
    }
    default: {
        // handle other types of concrete events 
    }
}
```

In the unit test, I simulate a test observable to pump a set concrete event type, then I can do

```
testScheduler.AdvanceBy(n)
```

I can test every section of my business logic.

However, now I have to create the concrete type of each event and put them in the observable.

I do have to mock some data entities, as some relies on an additional type, which cannot be mocked, that's why I have an interface of this data object. One example is, I wrap the `BrokeredMessage` so I can call the `CompleteAsync` from interface instead the actual unmockable `BrokeredMessage`.

How do I use MOQ to mock a data object so pattern matching will work?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible instead to change `class Event1` to `interface Event1`? It could make your life easier...

Comment: hmm, I have about 5 different data types under the top interface, that means I will have to create 5 different sub-interface to test my block? I feel that's a little unnecessary. I could expose an enum in the interface, and then instead of using pattern matching, I just compare enum. then I have to explicitly cast.... /facepalm

Comment: there must have something can make our life easier, right? I like this descriptive pattern matching style, but it is impossible to mock without going back to the old way

Comment: I am not sure if you can archive this with moq. The options are either to use `interface` or redesign your solution not to use pattern match(for example use base class with virtual method...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just hit the same issue, for my use case it was no problem to go back to the old way and not use pattern matching.

But it ought to be possible to roll your own test doubles and pass them in e.g.

`public class TestEvent1 : Event1 {}`

Make any methods you want to override virtual and you can fake them in your test code.

More work than Moq, but it would allow the pattern matching to be testable without changing the SUT to match the tests.